# How safe is my mcrypt function?

Tags: php, encryption, base64, mcrypt

i have to protect some really sensitive information
so excuse me if this is not your typical kind question
I needed a two way encryption function (encryption -> decryption) and i found this

```
    function encrypt($mprhase) {
        $MASTERKEY = "some key here";
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $MASTERKEY, $iv);
        $crypted_value = mcrypt_generic($td, $mprhase);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return base64_encode($crypted_value);
    } 
    function decrypt($mprhase) {
        $MASTERKEY = "some key here";
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $MASTERKEY, $iv);
        $decrypted_value = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($mprhase));
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return $decrypted_value;
    }
```

so, is there a way to enhance this function so the cracking to be nearly impossible to do.

thanks in advance

Comment: This is better suited at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sure, lose the master key after you finish crypting. that'll make it nearly impossible to decrypt the text.

Comment: Or post at http://crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: 1) It's weak. No authentication and ECB mode. 2) It doesn't even work.